# Save Databricks notebook as a HTML file programmatically

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I searched many threads in different forums but unfortunately did not find a solution to my problem.

I would like to save my Databricks Notebook after executing it as an HTML file with the output of cells.

I know there is an option to save the file manually using File >> Export >> HTML, but is there an option to use some method in the last cell that will do this without manually clicking?

I mean something similar to:
`!jupyter nbconvert  your_notebook_name.ipynb --to html`

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run similar code in the notebook,  will be then exported to the local disk of the driver node not to your computer, as code is executed in the cloud.

One approach to get it as HTML to your local disk, is to use [Export command of Workspace REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#export) or [corresponding command of Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html)

Comment: Is it possible to save the HTML to the mounted data lake or DBFS?

Comment: yes, you can put output to the `/dbfs/....`

Comment: So to export the HTML to the DBFS should I use the following: `databricks workspace export --overwrite --format HTML"/Users/someone@example.com/My Python Notebook" /dbfs/....`

Comment: Similar to that but it should be in %sh block and you need to setup authentication - host name and token. From notebook it could be better to use rest api

Comment: Thank you Alex! It is really helpful. I'm wondering if there is a possibility to save the output of the specific cell to the file on the dbfs?

Comment: not individual cell...